# UIViewController edges not extended behind top/bottom bars during a UINavigationController animation if it has a translucent UIToolbar subview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm displaying a translucent UIToolbar as a subview of a UIViewController which is a child of a UINavigationController (I don't use the UINavigationController toolbar as I want to subclass it).

Everything works fine but one thing: when I push another UIViewController on the UINavigationController stack, the next UIViewController edges are not extended behind the NavigationBar until the animation is over. The same issue occurs when the pop animation of the next UIViewController starts.

Side notes:

- The NavigationBar is translucent (by default)
- Both UIViewControllers are set to extend edges under top and bottom bars
- The issue is not reproducible if the UIToolbar is not translucent (of if a tint is set).
- The same issue occurs if the UINavigationController is inside a UITabBarController: the next UIViewController edges are not extended under the tabBar.

It's easily reproducible on iOS 12 and iOS 13 devices/simulators, with no code, just storyboard editing.

Does anyone has any clue regarding what's looks like a UINavigationController push/pop animation issue to me?

Here is what it looks like:[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Still happening on iOS 15.5. Only workarounds that come to mind are to (a) disable translucency for the UIToolbar or (b) change the background of the pushed view controller to `.systemBackground` or `.systemGroupedBackground`. Neither fully achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

I don't observe any such issue checked on iOS 13.2 in iPhone 11 Simulator. [image]

Comment: Because you missed the translucent UIToolbar part ;)
With an opaque uitoolbar or no uitoolbar at all, the issue does no’s occur.

Comment: How are you setting translucent UIToolbar?

Comment: It's translucent by default, otherwise there's a dedicated checkbox in the UIToolbar attributes inspector in IB.

Comment: Yes, then it is translucent by default for me as well. And I didn't face this issue.

Comment: There's no UIToolbar in your GIF, have you carefully read the description? In my GIF, you can see the UIToolbar in the middle. This is the translucent UIToolbar that makes the issue occur.

Comment: You are right .I overlooked that, I could see the issue.